# The difference between the 1st and 2nd editions. "Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools" by Aho, Sethi and Ullman

Tags: automata-theory, context-free, compilers, books

I bought "Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools 1st Edition" by Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi and Jeffrey D. Ullman long years ago and it has been sitting on my bookshelf ever since.

I have only flipped through the pages of this book since I bought it.

In the meantime, the second edition was released.

I guess this book is very difficult for me.

I am reading "Introduction to the Theory of COMPUTATION" by Michael Sipser right now in preparation for reading this book.

Is it better to buy "Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools 2nd Edition"?

I would like to know the difference between the 1st and 2nd editions.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.